# Use old raid drive as boot device without data loss

Tags: centos, software-raid, mdadm, raid1, grub

There were two disks in sw-raid. There were `/dev/md1` as swap, `/dev/md2` as boot and a `/dev/md3` with `ext4`.

The sw-raid was disabled by stopping and removing `mdadm` and then zeroing the superblock on each `/dev/mdX` partition with:

```
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda1
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda2
sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda3
```

In the disk that is the first boot device, I don't know if it's relevant, the system type of each partition was set back from `fd` to `82` or `83` with `fdisk`, `/etc/fstab` was updated, changing `/dev/mdX` to `/dev/sdaX`, and `grub` was reinstalled on the boot partition (`/dev/sda2`) with `grub-instal`. But the system wont boot.

What else should I do to use this disk as the boot device without reinstall or data loss?

Current output of `fdisk`

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    33556480    16777216+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *    33558528    34607104      524288+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3        34609152  3907027120  1936208984+  83  Linux
```

With **it doesn't boot** I mean that it stops in the grub console (with the `grub>` symbol). A `ls` command says:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
```

It's weird because hd1 was formatted with ext4...

Comment: That would normally be enough, in my experience (thought I'm not sure about the zeroing-the-superblock bit - how did you do that?).  Could you be more precise about what the system does when "*the system won't boot*"?

Comment: OK on the superblock-zeroing.  Is `/dev/sda2` tagged as bootable in the partition table?  And I repeat my question about *how* it fails to boot.

Comment: Added the command used. I can't really see what happens on boot, I only have access via ssh. All I know is that I can't connect after reboot (it was working perfectly before). Now I'm using a rescue system.

Comment: Yes, it is. Added the output of fdisk.

Comment: Without console access, or at least a pair of eyes on it, this will be very, very hard to diagnose.  Should I take your comment about a "rescue system" to mean that this is a virtualised system?

Comment: It's a physical system, a dedicated server. Added what happens after boot.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, it was a problem of the grub installation. I ran `grub` from the mounted fs (the rescue system didn't have the `grub` command) and the did:

```
grub> root (hd0,1)
grub> setup (hd0)
```